# SVG animation lines erratic behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

I am trying to animate lines going from left, right, top and bottom(lines should start from edges of the screen). Animation works fine in IE11 but not in Mozilla and Chrome. Other browsers I haven't tested. I used Adobe Illustrator to draw.  http://codepen.io/Ljanmi/pen/WbyLWv

In Chrome and Mozilla(IE11 is fine and acts normal) if in Illustrator I set Object>Artboards>Fit To Artwork Bounds(minimizing Artboard size which I usually do when create or edit SVG) I get this result(even worse) - http://codepen.io/Ljanmi/pen/yyqVqz

I spent hours and hours trying to figure out on my own without success. I started topics on GSAP forum and CSS tricks forum(stackoverflow.com is limiting me to post only 2 links as a newcomer).

I used GSAP JS library for animating(generally very happy with GSAP) but animation behaves the same if I use CSS3 to animate. I concluded that it is not related to GSAP(viewbox size property seems to have little bit of effect here) , more likely to be related to SVG structure itself or browser compatibility or both. So I guess there must be some work around to make it work like I would like to. I most likely lack some SVG/HTML/CSS3 knowledge since I am not very experienced but trying to learn as much as I can. Thanks everybody for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `svg { overflow: visible }` and it should work the same in all browsers (longer explanation below). If you want to see why the lines get clipped, add borders to the svg element.

Another way is to make sure the size of the svg matches what you want, e.g by using css.

All browsers except IE implemented `hidden` as the initial value for the `overflow` property for the <svg> element, as called for by the SVG 1.1 spec. SVG 2 has changed this for (outermost) inline svg elements, such that it requires what IE11 is currently doing. It will take some time before that gets changed in all browsers, so for now just add the `overflow: visible` rule and it should work correctly in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks Erik, this is amazing explanation. I was in trouble with this issue for a couple of days. The idea of overflow property crossed my mind to be honest but just guess I wasn't confident enough to actually try and implement it. Blazing fast reply and 100% working solution! You got 5 star answer and solution!!! Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble with browsers still not showing the overflowed content for SVGs and found that this finally got past it:

```
svg:not(:root) {
   overflow: visible !important;
}
```